# Run task only if host does not belong to a mare than one group

Tags: ansible

Run task only if host does not belong more than one group:

eg:

[web_1]

[one_web_2]

[server_3]

I whant to mach on first two groups:

"'web' not in group_names"  ->>  first and second

?

Comment: You should probably find what you are looking for in the `group_names` variable for a given host. I'd be happy to transform that to an answer if you clarify what your want to do exactly because I did not totally get it from your question.

Comment: This https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables is a good read for your problem

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Special Variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) *group_names*

> group_names List of groups the current host is part of

The play below shows how many from the selected groups (*my_groups*) the host is a member of.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_groups: [ 'web_1', 'web_2', 'web_3' ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} is member of
              {{ my_groups|intersect(group_names)|length }} group(s)."
```

Let's have the inventory below

```
[test]
test_01
test_02
test_03

[web_1]
test_01
test_02

[web_2]
test_01
test_02

[web_3]
test_03
```

The play gives

```
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "test_01 is member of 2 group(s)."
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": "test_02 is member of 2 group(s)."
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "msg": "test_03 is member of 1 group(s)."
}
```

Use the play below to

> Run task only if host does not belong more than one group

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_groups: [ 'web_1', 'web_2', 'web_3' ]
  tasks:
    - fail:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} is member of
              {{ my_groups|intersect(group_names)|length }} groups.
              Play failed."
      when: my_groups|intersect(group_names)|length != 1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} is member of
              {{ my_groups|intersect(group_names)|length }} group.
              Play continues."
```